# ASP.NET MVC 5 routing, hide data in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two types of functionality for a action with a `bool` variable.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult action(bool data = false)
{
   if(data == false)
   {
      return View("view1");
   }
   else
   {
      return View("view2");
   }
}
```

It is a `[httpGet]` method. some link has data bool value as `true` and some has `false`.
The url has the attribute like `http://localhost:58241/action?data=False`
I want to hide the `?data=False` or `?data=True`from URL and should possess all the same functionality like before.

I want the URL like `http://localhost:58241/action`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing has absolutely nothing at all to do with query string parameters. And in any case, you still need to transfer the `data` parameter to the server for the action method to receive it. There are 3 ways to do this:

1. Pass it in the URL using HTTP GET (as a route value or query string value)
2. Pass it in the form body using HTTP POST
3. Pass it in a model (using HTTP POST and model binding)

The simplest option is #1, however since you mentioned this isn't acceptable to pass the data through the URL, your only choice is to use HTTP post. So, the rest of this answer uses #2.

First, the default route does not cover your choice of URL (`/action`), so you need to insert a custom route for this.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Add route to handle /action
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Action",
            url: "action",
            defaults: new { controller = "Data", action = "Action" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Next, you need a controller to handle both the GET and POST from the browser.

```
public class DataController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Action()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action(bool data = false)
    {
        if (data)
        {
            return View("view2");
        }

        return View("view1");
    }
}
```

The data is sent back to the server in the POST, so it is not required to pass it in the URL.

Finally, you have the view (named `Action.cshtml`) that is returned from the `Action` action method. It has 2 different form tags that submit a different value for `data` depending on the button clicked.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Action";
}

<h2>Choose an Option</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "Data")) {

    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" value="With Data" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "Data")) {

    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="false" />
    <input type="submit" value="Without Data" />
}
```

Note that you could do this step entirely in JavaScript (AJAX POST) if you please, which would enable you to use a hyperlink instead of a button or you could just style the button using CSS to look like a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality partially by making the parameter optional as suggested by @VishalSuthar. But for one condition you must use the parameter if you want to access it using a GET request.

Else, if you make the `Action` only accessible by POST requests, this part will be easier to implement. In that case only change you need is :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult action(bool data = false)
{
   if(data == false)
   {
      return View("view1");
   }
   else
   {
      return View("view2");
   }
}
```

This way you can pass the parameter in form and hit the action with the URL showing: *http://localhost:58241/action*

**Note:** This way the action will not be accessible via GET requests.