# Hide my DB row id in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I don't want a number in the URL of my MVC app.

So is there any way to change the default id value type from integer to hexadecimal in MVC?

Or

Any other way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Use encryption.

Comment: Why would a hexadecimal value be any better?  You can make the parameter type a string instead of an integer, I suppose.  But the value is still *visible*, it's not hidden in any way.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I assume you want to pass a parameter around. You could do that in a Cookie, an Http Header, a Post request, etc. If all you want to avoid is the parameter being visible in the browser bar, you could also transfer it via ajax. But the main question remains: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392933/asp-net-mvc-5-routing-hide-data-in-url